# How do I view the errors that occured in a skelta workflow?

Tags: .net, workflow, business-process-management, skelta

I have a skelta workflow that has "finished with errors" according to the WorkflowExecutionReport. Unfortunately I can't see any way to actually see what the errors were so I can figure out what went wrong.

Does any one know how one goes about viewing these errors?

Comment: Don't waste your time looking through that log, we used to use skelta but gave up, product is not tested very well and the support sucks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view in two ways. Skelta Logger Console and Skelta Logs.

1. Skelta Logger Console

The Skelta Logger Console is a utility that shows a real-time log of events during the execution of Skelta BPM.NET. It is automatically installed in the C:\Program Files\Skelta\BPM.NET \Bin folder when Skelta BPM.NET  is installed.

Browse to the location of the Skelta Logger Console and double click on the SkeltaLoggerConsole executable.

This opens the Skelta Logger Console log in a new window. You can view the events as they occur when Skelta BPM.NET is running.

The SkeltaLoggerConsole will display the events using the three types of log categories to identify the type of information.

2. Skelta Logs

From Skelta Logs you can view the errors created by Skelta BPM.NET.

Two types of Log files are created.

The first type of Log file, for generic log messages, will be created in the path - C:\Program Files\Skelta\BPM.NET \Logs. The Log files are saved in this folder using the date of logging as the filename with the format "MMDDYYYY" (there will be one Log file for each day).

The second type of Log file is application-specific; it will log messages related to applications. These Log files are created in separate folders corresponding to each application. The folders are located in the path C:\Program Files\Skelta\BPM.NET \Logs and are saved with names in the format "+n" where "n" is a serial number of the log folder created.

To view the Log files,

Browse to the location of the log files using the relevant path, i.e., "\Logs" or "\Logs\" depending on the type of Log file you wish to view. Select the log file to view by looking for the date of logging. 
Open the log file in a text editor. It will display all the events of the day using the three types of log categories to identify the type of information.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there isn't any way to view the error in the WorkfloeExecutionReport page. You have to look in the log that Skelta generates called Skelta.wfengine.log. I found that it contains the stack trace of the exception that was thrown during execution.